# Send ESC command to dismiss a browser alert

Tags: robotframework

The task is to dismiss an alert with this two different ways:

1) sending an `ESC`;

2) clicking on cancel button (done).

I need to send a `ESC` to dismiss a browser alert.
This is a automating task and I am using the Robotframework and its `SeleniumLibrary`.

To handle the Alert, this library offers keywords like `Handle Alert`. But it does not solve my 1st  problem, since I specifically need to send the `ESC`. I also attempted to use `Press Key`, neither no success due to alert itself.

I've been checking some `javascript` alternatives, but I have few experience with it.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Note: already attempted to use some python libraries and create, but I have some restrictions that block me to use.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Have you made sure the alert window has focus before using “Press Key”?

Comment: Not sure how the alert works. Is it a window? I used the [Get Window Handles](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Window%20Handles) to list the window, but the alert window isn't listed. So possibly is already in focus.
And when I use `Press Key  <locator>  <esc>`, occurs an error saying that there is a alert window.

Comment: The alerts are a borwser/OS component - attached to the same os frame (window) created for the browser itself - thus not present when `Get Window Hadles` is used. And they can't be addressed through selenium's webelement methods (they are not part of the DOM) - thus `Press Key` can't be used, there's no locator to pass. Sorry, can't help you with that, just saying what and why will not work :) You might try cooking something with `ActionChains`, though success with it is also highly questionable.

Comment: Just go with `Handle Alerts`,  it is designed precisely for them. I can imagine your requirements including "... and the alerts must be dismissable with the Esc key!", but that's a standard browser component (we can't/shouldn't test every 3rd part dependency, some things are taken for granted), it's sufficient to be tested manually.

Comment: @Felipe If possible you should share what's you have try here .

Comment: @Todor thanks for suggesting it, but it'll not work due to the driver. The robotframework does not show or return any webdriver opened. Thank you again.

Comment: @Felipe If you still got eorr , you should build your own kewordy by using python library pynput .